# Require js ruins code navigation

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, requirejs, pycharm, js-amd

`require.js` states the way of defining objects inside modules with `define([requiremens], object)` as best way.

So every page, or other js file, will do `require()` call and receive modules as parameters.

This works pretty fine, each function/module has own namespace.

The problem is that I have:

```
// AJAX/Requests.js

define(['UI/Message'],function(Message){
var Requests={
    checkResponse:function(response){
        //1==ok
        //0==error
        //2==good message
        //3==good message, but still stop
        if(response.status==1){
            return true;
        }
        else if(response.status==2){
            Message.good(response.message);
            return true;
        }
        else if(response.status==3){
            Message.good(response.message);
            return false;
        }
        else{
            Message.bad(response.message);
            return false;
        }
    }
};
return Requests;
});
```

Now the UI/Message is defined in the same way, and it returns object.

But when I edit file with requests, I can't navigate by code, so if I want to edit Message object, the only way is to go and open file the myself and to find function I need, rather than have the IDE jump there for me.

Is there some workaround for pycharm specifically or to require.js in common to solve this issue? When you have a lot of code it becomes a mess to navigate it, which is why I use an IDE in the first place!

And what worse: The editor never knows what functions objects have!

The one possible solution I can see is to not to use enclosed namespaces, and to declare global variable before the `define()` call, but in this case all objects shall be called like UI_Message, AJAX_Requests. In order to be sure, that I don't have some Message in two different locations....

And I am not sure, if require.js optimizer will use this correctly. Require.js documentation  states very clear, to stay away from global variables.

Comment: Was this fixed?

Answer (score 8):

It's a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-7282), please star/vote.

From the issue description:

> The dojo library switched to AMD's format define() for loading modules
>   instead of dojo.require(). Previously I was able to use Ctrl+B on
>   dojo.require('path.to.someJs') to jump to the declaration. This does
>   not work on the new format define(['path/to/someJs]', ...).

As PyCharm, WebStorm, PhpStorm and IntelliJ IDEA share the same JavaScript plug-in, this issue also applies to the product that you are using. You will continue to observe the described problem until this bug is fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: JetBrains has implemented the basics on this issue, however, they still don't support paths configuration (you're limited to relative paths), and you have to click on the define itself to get to the module.  :(

Comment: It's improving in WebStorm 8.  The asked for features *Find Usages* and *Go To Declaration* [work already now](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21954895/623816), refactoring still needs some improvements.

Answer (score 3):

WebStorm (at least 6.0.2) supports code navigation with RequireJs if you're defining your modules with the [CommonJs wrapper](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) and use the **exports** and module arguments:

```
//foo.js
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    //use exports to expose properties for code navigation in other modules
    exports.bar = function() {}
});
```

Apparently, it works even if the module using it doesn't use the CommonJs wrapper format:

```
define(['./foo'], function(foo) {
    foo.bar(); //code navigation works here
}
```

If the other IDEs use the same JavaScript plug-in as CrazyCoder said, it may work on their newer releases as well.