# Resolving "Unresolved function or method observable()" warning using KnockoutJS in PyCharm

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, pycharm

PyCharm (professional edition, v2017.1.4) is failing to pick up any intellisense for KnockoutJS references such as these:

[image]

I've managed to resolve this in the past when using WebStorm; from what I recall, it boiled down to ensuring there was a KnockoutJS reference under *Javascript > Libraries*:

[image]

However, although I've done this (including the "Definitely Typed" version of the lib, see above), the "unresolved" warnings persist in PyCharm.

Anyone have any bright ideas as to what may help clear these warnings?

---

**EDIT:**

Additional screenshots:

*Project interpreter settings*
[image: Project interpreter settings]

*Javascript Libraries settings*
[image: Javascript Libraries settings]

*RequireJS settings - points to debug v3.4.1 of KnockoutJS*

[image: RequireJS settings]

*ViewModel KO reference*

[image: ViewModel KO reference]

Unfortunately, even with the `js.knockout` reference, the issue persists.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is Javascript which you are developing in PyCharm, not Python in PyCharm, writing to the KnockoutJS API, correct?

Comment: Correct.  Originally I was using WebStorm, but as the license for that was gathering dust and we were already utilising the community edition of PyCharm for Python-based smoke tests, we switched to the pro edition to allow us to work with both in a single IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the library there, as well as in the python project interpreter which you are using.

1. `Settings | Project:myprj | Project Interpreter | '+'`

[image]

2. `Type in 'knockout'`
3. `Choose 'js.knockout'`
4. `Click Install Package`

[image]

Should be good now.

[image]

For reference, here are the javascript libraries I have.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, much appreciated.  Unfortunately adding the js.knockout lib doesn't appear to have resolved the issue though (see updated post above).

Comment: Does anything show up when you type `js.`? Does it see any methods at all? I'm not able to replicate your issue. Prior to me installing `js.knockout`, both `ko` and `observable` are being highlighted, but for you only `observable` is being highlighted. So it seems PyCharm is recognizing `ko` at least. So it seems like maybe `ko` is getting re-defined somehow. I'm not a javascript expert though. Btw, you have a config file that defines the kockout lib path, and I'm not doing that. Maybe try making a new project and only adding a javascript file and testing if it still persists?

Comment: Seems to be related somehow to Knockout being referenced via RequireJS. If I reference `window.ko`, I can see the various methods (`observable`, `observableArray`, etc), so I think you're right - it looks as though the RequireJS `ko` reference is redefining the `window.ko` reference being set by `js.knockout`.

Comment: Creating a bare-bones project with a straightforward `<script>` reference to KO works like a charm.

Comment: If this has resolved your problem, could you award the bounty?

Comment: Done - unfortunately it didn't appear to work for a RequreJS-based project, but for a bare-bones project, the above does the trick.  Thanks again for your time, it's much appreciated.

Comment: aw, sorry. I thought that you were able to get it to work like you wanted. Looks like this might be a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502682/require-js-ruins-code-navigation)